# Is there any way to stop Karma serving cached files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

So here's my issue. I'm trying to run a test suite for an old application of mine. However, I've stumbled upon the notorious Karma error: `Executed 0 of 0 ERROR`.

As I turn Karma's loglevel to debug, I realize that these lines are being printed:

```
DEBUG [web-server]: serving:     /home/**/**/**/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular/angular.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_es-ar.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-hateoas/src/angular-hateoas.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/ng-table/dist/ng-table.min.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-notify-toaster/toaster.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.tpl.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/sockjs/sockjs.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/stomp-websocket/lib/stomp.min.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/http-cas/src/http-cas.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/lodash/lodash.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/moment/moment.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/moment/locale/es.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/**/**/**/src/app/scripts/app.js
```

As you can tell, there are no specs. I try to add a spec file to the `files` array inside `karma.conf.js`, but to no avail. The same files are printed.

I'm assuming my problem is related with said caching.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

All the best,

Alejandro

Answer (score 1):

4 years late, but according to the [karma file definition](https://karma-runner.github.io/6.3/config/files.html) you can set the nocache-attribute to `true`.

In case your file-definition in the karma.conf.js looks like this:

`files: ['src/app/scripts/app.js']`

you should change it to

`files: [pattern: 'src/app/scripts/app.js', nocache: true]`

This will stop serving the files from cache.